# "Error: comparison between pointer and integer" when compiling c++ code

Tags: c++

In C++ (compiler : clang++), when compiling the following code:

```
char* strcpy(char * dest, const char * src)
{
    char* result = dest;
    if(('\0' != dest) && ('\0' != src))
    {
        /* Start copy src to dest */
        while ('\0' != *src)
        {
            *dest++ = *src++;
        }
        /* put '\0' termination */
        *dest = '\0';
    }
    return result;

}
```

I get the following error code:

```
string/strcpy.cpp:12:11: error: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'char *')
        if(('\0' != dest) && ('\0' != src))
            ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
string/strcpy.cpp:12:29: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int'
      and 'const char *')
        if(('\0' != dest) && ('\0' != src))
```

I'm aware that most of the errors related with this error are produced when the characters to compare are between quotation marks instead of apostrophes, but in this code this is not the case. Why is this error produced? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part of the error messages confuses you?

Comment: `dest` is a pointer. `*dest` is the value of the thing it points to. You compare correctly later with `'\0' != *src`. Seems like a simple typo to me.

Comment: `strcpy` bad name.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That fixed the code, thx

Comment: @manni66 In the freestanding environment that I'm using strcpy is a valid name

Comment: @Rottenheimer2 It's been pointed out that you likely meant to check those pointers for `nullptr`. In that case, that correction won't do what you want it to do.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes I saw it right after posting the comment

Comment: @Rottenheimer2 It may be in your environment, but I once lost several hours learning the hard way that `strlen` was implemented with a macro, resulting in utterly incomprehensible error messages all because I had a variable named `strlen` that was tracking, gasp!, the length of a string and I've been wary ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean

```
if((NULL != dest) && (NULL != src))
```

of even more idiomatic

```
if((dest) && (src))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
('\0' != dest)
```

In the above, `'\0'` is a char literal, but `dest` is a **pointer** to a char. This is the reason for the error being thrown.

I believe the problem would be fixed if you change the conditional to

```
('\0' != *dest)
```

EDIT: Whoops, I thought you were trying to check if the string is at it's end. If you were trying to check if the pointer is null, the correct way would be to simply evaluate it as conditional.

```
if(dest)
```

Comment: Oddly enough, although the correction you propose would indeed resolve the type mismatch, I don't think it's the right correction for the context.  It doesn't make sense.  I think the OP means to perform null-pointer checks there.